# Clauses as objects of the verb "appreciate"

Tags: usage

[Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage](https://books.google.es/books?id=w1WuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA61&dq=%22%20Gowers%E2%80%99%20suggestion%20that%20it%20is%20best%20to%20avoid%20using%20the%20construction%22&hl=es&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q=%22%20Gowers%E2%80%99%20suggestion%20that%20it%20is%20best%20to%20avoid%20using%20the%20construction%22&f=false) reads

> There is some justification in Sir Ernest Gowers’ suggestion that it
> is best to avoid using the construction **appreciate** followed by a
> *how* or a *that* clause.

Why is it so?

Comment: If you continue reading after your quoted part, there are several examples given.

Comment: You need to post examples, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

A reprint of the 1983 paperback edition says:

> "**appreciate** is overworked as a synonym of *understand* or *recognize* in
> official and business letters, especially in *It is
> appreciated that* to introduce a recognition of the point of view of
> the person addressed or *you will appreciate that* to ask him to
> recognize the writer's. This tendency to wander can be restrained by
> using the word only with a noun as its object.

Comment: In particular it's worse than "sympathise", "understand", "realise", etc, which express that the writer is properly aware of the reader's concerns and is not making the decision lightly. "Appreciate" has connotations of thinking something is good - compare "I appreciate that your father is dead", "I appreciate the music of Beethoven".